# Sending detailed email of exception in Mule ESB using SMTP connector

Tags: xml, mule, mule-el

I have a "Catch Exception Strategy" in my flow and I use the SMTP connector to send an email to the admin (me).

I am able to send the exception using `#[exception]` but I would like to send a more detailed message including :

- The complete URL requests
- The original payload sent
- The converted payload
- (Optional but would be great) The complete stacktrace and time of the error     like in the console.

I tried to use an Expression component and Variables  to store those information. I also tried with the variable component but that didn't work either. All my variables are always set to null in the message.

Here's my flow :

```
    <flow name="PivotalContactById" >
                <https:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="host" port="port" doc:name="HTTP (Deprecated)" path="path"/>
                <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <set-variable variableName="flowVars.url" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.context.url']" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="flowVars.originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
                <scripting:component doc:name="GroovyContactIDJsonToXML">
                    <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="pivotalContactById_JSON_to_XML.groovy"></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
                <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <set-variable variableName="flowVars.convertedPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer1" operation="GetContactById" doc:name="Pivotal SOAP Web Service"/>
                <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
                <set-payload value="#[exception] #[flowVars.url] #[flowVars.originalPayload] #[flowVars.convertedPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="host" to="dude@dude.org" from="adminmule@dude.org" subject="Exception yo" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: Provide the VariableName=url alone ( Not flowVars.url) while setting it in flow level. When you accessing it in Catch Exception Strategy set as #[flowVars.url] or #[flowVars['url']] .Try this.

Comment: This seems to work thanks! Do you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flow Level, please provide the variableName = url alone(Not as flowVars.url). When accessing it in Catch Exception Strategy set as  `#[flowVars.url]` or `#[flowVars['url']]`.